# GXT Grid PagingListStore

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am using a grid that uses pagination, so it uses a ListLoader/MemoryProxy to manage the pages. But in this case the store, at any given time, is only aware of the items in the current page. I am also using a GroupingView which supports sorting (remoteSort=false). But it only sorts on what's in the store, i.e the current page. But if a group extends to a second page, the sorting doesn't take into account the group's entries on the other page, so that sorting in this case is incorrect. Does anyone have a solution or ideas on how to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is trying to map your idea of a "page" to a "group" - if you page through results in consistently-sized pages, chances are excellent that this will not match up with your groups. For example, as long as groups only have a few items each, you'll probably get *close* to your expected page size (plus or minus a few items), but you'll have to account for that while paging. But what happens when a group (or several groups in a row) are the size of a page or larger?

For example, say you set your page size to 25 items, and that 3 groups are on their way, A with 15 items, B with 20 items, C with 50. If the first page has 25 items, then either

1. there are 15 A items and no B items (so that the group isn't broken up and page isn't too big)
2. there are 15 A items and 10 B items (so that the page is the right size)
3. there are 15 A items and 20 B items (so that the group isn't broken up and the page has at least 25 items, but is bigger than expected).

Okay, so that's a bit annoying. It does get worse though when we consider the second page of items:

1. The page has to start at item 16 instead of 26, and has only 20 B items (still frustrating if you expect to see enough items and how have blank space in a large sized grid).
2. The page starts at item 16 with 20 B items, then 5 C items (not quite as bad as your described case since B is complete, but C isn't - still frustrating if you expect to see the group together).
3. The page starts at item 36 with all 50 C items (might stop the browser at extremes of 100 or 1000 items in a group).

Fortunately, all of this is easy to implement: the server tells the client what it paged back in, in the paging results object, with the actual offset and items that it sends (which may or may not be what the client requested).

---

Setting remote sort to false with paging doesn't make any sense, since the server has to sort (or group, which is a kind of sort) to get you groups in a consistent way. That said, if your query does it anyway, the grouping view has to be sure the items are correctly grouped. As with the paging details, it doesn't actually matter to the client if they are sorted or not (it might matter to the *user*...) as long as items within a group are next to each other (since the view won't reorder the items again).

Comment: Thanks for the good ideas. In my case the page size is fixed. I can return a variable number of items from my proxy, but the paging toolbar requires the page size and uses that to calculate the number of pages, which it displays in the toolbar text. Looking at the paging toolbar source, I  don't see any easy way to override this behavior without replacing the onLoad method (not doable since it references private field).

Comment: Yep, it has to make some assumptions - but how else would you have it do that? You've already said that "pages" don't make any sense when combined with "groups", so I think a paging toolbar is likely the problem here - either send much bigger pages, or build a "group" toolbar that understands the data it is sending, or a "group-aware paging toolbar" which never pretends to show the page count, and only stops showing "next" page button when on the last page. This would also mean you can't skip to another page number. That may or may not work for your use case.

Comment: Consider updating your question based on these new thoughts, perhaps I can offer other concrete suggestions, but as I think we've both made clear, conventional "paging" and "grouping" don't really get along well...

Comment: I think something along the lines of a PagingStore might be useful. Then the paging toolbar won't need a loader to work and I can use local sorting.

Comment: If your entire data set can be loaded locally, then yes, that will work fine - effectively though you will have to have the full list of items already sorted (to be grouped). You won't even need a paging toolbar, since you can just show all groups (and keep in mind that the paging toolbar will still try to chunk your data into pages, even though nothing is loading from the server).